# Magnolia CMS seamingly ignores mysql database but doesn't use derby

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, tomcat8, ubuntu-16.04, magnolia

I have a Magnolia-CMS running on a **Debian** system and on a **Windows** system.

- **Windows** (local dev):

  - Tomcat 7 (through maven plugin)
  - Java 8
  - MySQL 5.7
- **Debian** (current live):

  - Tomcat 7
  - Java 7
  - MySQL 5.5

My goal is to set up an **Ubuntu** system with

- **Ubuntu** (future live):

  - Tomcat 8 (also tried Tomcat 7 through maven plugin)
  - Java 8
  - MySQL 5.7

My problem is that every time I try to restore a backup from current live system (**Debian**), Magnolia completely ignores the contents of the database and shows an empty instance. Default users, default config, empty website and assets...

I've tried to do the following:

- Replace webapp with freshly compiled one
- (Start up to get a clean instance, doesn't make a differnce)
- Replace this webapp's repositories folder with a backup from **Debian** (and remove the index-folders)
- Import the MySQL dump from **Debian** into **Windows** / **Ubuntu**
- Clean up permissions on either Linux
- Start up

The startup process of tomcat is awfully short on **Ubuntu** (on **Windows** it takes way longer) and after it's finished, the Magnolia-instance is completely empty/fresh. The database contains at least the websites of the **Debian** system, though. On **Windows** everything works as expected.

I don't even know where to start. Has anyone a hint what I have to look for or experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the error was in the configuration of the MySQL server.

To cope with Windows' case insensitiveness I added `lower_case_table_names = 1` to the my.cnf and stored it under /etc/my.cnf.

On Ubuntu, this particular setting seems to be overridden by another config, so I had to add this line to /etc/mysql/my.cnf to get it through as global configuration.

Because of this missing piece, the Magnolia instances added a second set of talbes to the schema, which was - of cource - empty.

This also explained, why there were no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Open `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/<yourMagnoliaContext>/WEB-INF/config/default/magnolia.properties` and look where `magnolia.repositories.home` points to. That's the location of the FS part of your repo ... most likely going to be something different on windows.
Also, in same properties file check `magnolia.repositories.jackrabbit.config` that points to the DB config file your Magnolia will use ... most likely again something different on Win than on Linux. Make sure that config file points to correct DB instance and correct schema.

Also perhaps worth reading:
[Configuration Management](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuration+management)
[Multiple configurations deployment](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/WAR+file+with+multiple+configurations)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I use relative paths for the configuration, so they are identical under Windows and Linux. Also the Database uses the same configuration.

Good guess, though!